# UI of sign in with LinkedIn SDK is broken

Tags: ios, sdk, linkedin-api, ios10

I have implemented a solution to sign in to my app with a LinkedIn account. When the user clicks on that option the LinkedIn SDK checks for the existence of the native LinkedIn app. If the app exists, the user gets redirected to the LinkedIn app where he is asked if he wants to allow my application to have access to the profile overview and email address.

Unfortunately this view is broken, see screenshots below (the first one taken from an iPhone 6, the second one from an iPhone 6s). Since this is part of the LinkedIn app there is no way for me to fix it. I have implemented the LinkedIn SDK 6 months ago and have not touched it since. The broken view must be rather new.

Could you please tell me what causes this and can you fix it? As you can see on the second screenshot, there is no way the user knows where to "accept", so this is crucial.

[image]
[image]

Comment: We have the same problem, we checked today, but it's still not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. We fixed it by updating the "Application Logo" inside the Developer console for LinkedIn.

If you go the your app -> Settings -> There is an "Application Logo" input, which showed an error before which gave us that white overlay. After adding a complete white square PNG image the white overlay disappeared.